# Referencia a variable miembro estática sin definir en C++

Tags: c++, make, cmake

Me da el siguiente error y la verdad... tras horas mirando y mirando... no entiendo el motivo.

Error:

> ➜  build git:(master) ✗ make [ 20%] Building CXX object
>   src/CMakeFiles/App.dir/App.cpp.o [ 40%] Linking CXX static library
>   libApp.a [ 40%] Built target App [ 60%] Building CXX object
>   src/CMakeFiles/MLog.dir/MLog.cpp.o [ 80%] Building CXX object
>   src/CMakeFiles/MLog.dir/App.cpp.o [100%] Linking CXX executable MLog
>   CMakeFiles/MLog.dir/App.cpp.o: En la función `App::getApp()':
>   App.cpp:(.text+0x50): referencia a`App::app' sin definir
>   App.cpp:(.text+0x71): referencia a `App::app' sin definir
>   App.cpp:(.text+0x78): referencia a`App::app' sin definir collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   src/CMakeFiles/MLog.dir/build.make:126: fallo en las instrucciones
>   para el objetivo 'src/MLog' make[2]: *** [src/MLog] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:87: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
>   'src/CMakeFiles/MLog.dir/all' make[1]: ***
>   [src/CMakeFiles/MLog.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:83: fallo en las
>   instrucciones para el objetivo 'all' make: *** [all] Error 2

El CMakeList.txt:

```
add_library(App App)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MLog MLog App)
target_link_libraries(MLog App)
```

App.h:

```
#ifndef _APP
#define _APP

#include <iostream>

class App
{
        public:
                void getMensaje();
                static App *getApp();

        protected:
                App();

        private:
                static App *app;

};
#endif
```

App.cpp:

```
#include "App.h"

App::App()
{
}

void App::getMensaje()
{
        std::cout << "Esta es la url" << std::endl;
}

App *App::getApp()
{
        if(!app)
        {
          app = new App();
        }
        return app;
}
```

MLog.cpp:

```
#include "App.h"


        App *monitor = 0;

int main()
{
        App *app = monitor->getApp();
        app->getMensaje();
}
```

Comment: Creo recordar que, en C++11, **si** se pueden *declarar* y *asignar* a la vez, en el archivo `App.h`, poniendo `private: static App *app = nullptr;`, pero no estoy seguro. Prueba y comentas.

Comment: Efectivamente como apuntas en la respuesta me faltaba asignarla. Sobre lo que comentas ahora, haciéndolo en el archivo de cabecera no me lo permite, me dice:  App.h:17:21: error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘App* App::app’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
   static App *app = nullptr;

Comment: Siguiendo [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/19610), he editado el título, para facilitar las búsquedas a futuros usuarios. He eliminado lo de `make` y `cmake`, que es irrelevante. Espero que no te importe.

Comment: Para nada, debería haberlo hecho yo cuando se vio que el problema nada tenía que ver... con ambos XDDD gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que **instanciar** la variable estática `app`.

En C++, la instanciación de las variables estáticas se da en 2 pasos:

#### Declaración.

Lo tienes hecho en el archivo `App.h`.

```
static App *app;
```

#### Instanciación

Es lo que te falta. En `App.cpp`, después de los *includes*, haz

```
App *App::app = 0;
```

**sin** poner `static` ni nada, solo su tipo, nombre, y valor.
Con eso debería de bastar.